# Can capistrano v3 specify HOSTS in command line like v2 does?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

In Capistrano v2, I can run deploy on the server specified in the command-line.

`cap staging HOSTS="host1,host2" deploy`

How can I do the same thing in the Capistrano v3?

### example scenario

I have to scale my app, but I don't want to deploy all of my app servers. So I just want to run deploy on the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you found this or not but the documentation says you can just list it in the command line like this:

```
cap --hosts=server1,server2 production deploy
```

See documentation here:
[Host Filtering Docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/host-filtering/)

See code here:
[Code Filtering Link](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/1f86d32fd48d08311b92446e1db428613b180309/lib/capistrano/application.rb#L78)

Looking at the code, it appears to be able to accepts HOSTS also.

See test confirming this:
[Test Confirming Both Options](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/8de8fb3b2ed2d1e04d3070c8d220b71d862faaca/spec/lib/capistrano/configuration/servers/host_filter_spec.rb#L29)

Comment: This question is asked with capistrano `v3.0`. Any yes, I have seen this new feature in `v3.1`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: How can you read the `filters[:hosts]` value from within a capistrano script ?