# How do you deploy to only one server with Capistrano v3?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

How do you deploy to only one server with Capistrano v3? All the solutions I found out there deploy to every server, so, I would assume they are for v2.

I don't want to deploy a stage, I'm already using multistaging and I want to deploy to only one server in one of the stages.

Comment: What are "all the solutions [you] found"? Please provide some hints as to what will _not_ work to prevent time being wasted on non-helpful answers.

Comment: Looks like you need HOST and ROLE filter. Have you tried out as mentioned in the below link?        http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/role-filtering/                                                           Similar question was found in the following link too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783552/can-capistrano-v3-specify-hosts-in-command-line-like-v2-does?rq=1

Comment: My answer worked for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out, in Capistrano 3 the way to deploy specific parts of your app to a single server is making use of **[HOST filtering](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/host-filtering/)**. Let’s imagine that you are deploying directly to production and you have this configuration in `config/deploy/production.rb`

```
set :stage, :production


server "webserver1.example.com”,         roles: [:web]

server "appserver1.example.com",         roles: [:app]                   
server "appserver2.example.com",         roles: [:app]                   
server "appserver3.example.com",         roles: [:app]                        

server “dbserver1.example.com”,          roles: [:db]
server “dbserver2.example.com”,          roles: [:db]
```

Then if you want to deploy only to your webserver1, you just run the command:

```
cap --hosts=webserver1.example.com production deploy
```

Comment: I am running cap --host=foo production deploy and yet, capistrano, towards the end of deploying this rails application, connects to bar to run some task and fails because the release directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You must use settings **multistage**.

Capistrano 3.x is multistage **by default**.

In one of his stage you define only the server you want.

```
set :stage, :staging

server 'staging.zodiacmedia.co.uk', roles: %w{web app db}, port: 22

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/staging.example.com'
```

Run command:

```
cd /home/deploy/capistrano/example
cap staging something:to:do
```

This [tutorial](http://www.zodiacmedia.co.uk/blog/capistrano-3-tutorial-series-part-2) is old but may help you.

Comment: I'm already using multistage. I don't want to deploy to one stage, I one to deploy to one server of many in one of the stages.